# Difference between Infringement and transgression

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Here is the meanings of these two words according to the online Cambridge English dictionary:

- [transgression](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transgression): "the act or process of breaking a law or moral rule, or an example of this: (...)"
- [infringement](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/infringement): "an action that breaks a rule, law, etc.: (...)".

Both of them are same.
Could anyone explain the key difference with examples ?

Comment: The difference is not (necessarily) a matter of English but of legalese.

Answer (score 1):

In general, one **infringes** upon a *right*, whereas one **transgresses** a *limit* or, by extension, a *rule*.

This distinction is not very strong, though; not seldom will you see one word used instead of the other, even to the point of interchangeability.

The lack of a strict distinction can perhaps be explained by the origins of both words. *To infringe* is from Latin *infringo*, "to break"; *to transgress* is from Latin *transgredior*, "to step over". In both cases, it is easy to imagine carrying out the action on a rule and thereby violating it. Perhaps the present meaning of *infringe* lies in the idea that *in-* in *infringo* should represent "in(to)", as in breaking into a house or walled garden, even though I do not believe this sense pertains to the original Latin verb.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is subtle.  *Infringing* often implies a more minor action or incident (although doesn't preclude something more serious).  It also allows for lack of intent or for mere carelessness moreso than "transgression" does.

> If you aren't careful, you could start infringing upon his property rights.

A "transgression", on the other hand, implies something more serious, and perhaps more intentional:

> Intentionally building his garage over his neighbour's property line was a serious transgression of his neighbour's rights.

In many cases the words could be used interchangeably, but a transgression feels more serious than an infringement, in general.

Comment: So two sentence are  wrong according to your explanation.  

A series of patent **infringement** by a competitor forced Apple to sue for protection.  

Cheating on a final exam is, without a doubt, a major academic **transgression**

Comment: Further, except in a legal discussion, an *infringement* more often needs a preposition, as: an infringement *of/upon/against…*. By contrast a *transgression* is less uncomfortable by itself, as: *his transgressions were many*

Comment: @mr.wr When a word can be used in a generał srnse, and also has a legal usage, the legal meaning has to be very specific, and so it can be a little different from general usage.  That said, you can think of it this way: Someone who infringes on a patent rarely takes away _all_ the money the patent holder was expecting to make, just some of it.